# X64 memory page permission

Tags: memory-management, 64-bit, paging

Can I set specific memory page as Only executable not readable and writable?

I've heard that X86 and X64 has no X permission bit on the page table

and there is a NX bit for enforce R/X and R/W

But, can we allocate or set the specific page a executable only?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried gooogling that first?

Comment: Oh yeah I did and can find paper mention XnR

Comment: Then delete your post or answer to your own question yourself. This is fine here.

Comment: Okay it seems possible. I asked this question because lots of articles talk about the possibility of the non readable but executable script not a page. I would answer myself after reading that paper thanks